# Roots of unity in fixed field of decomposition group.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity, ramification

$\zeta_q\in L^{G({\frak P})}\Leftrightarrow$ if $\sigma\in$ $G(\frak p$) then $\sigma(\zeta_q)=\zeta_q\Leftrightarrow$ if $\sigma$ fixes $\frak P$ then $\sigma$ fixes $\zeta_q$.  What's next?

Suppose $L/k$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$.  For $\frak P$ an ideal of $\cal O$$_L$, the $decomposition$ $group$ $G(\frak P$) is the set {$\sigma\in G|\sigma(\frak P)=\frak P$}.  I am looking for roots of unity that appear in $L^{G({\frak P})}$.

Let $\zeta_q\in L$ denote the $q$-th primitive root of unity ($p$ either prime, or the power of a prime, not necessarily the one that lies over $\frak P$).  Then the above chain of equivalences is true.  What's next?  I know that does not imply $\zeta_q\in\frak P$.  Does that tell us anything about $\cal O$$_L/\frak P$?  I am having trouble making sense of it.  One-way implications are also sufficient.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your notation. Is $p$ related to $\mathfrak P$ in any way?

Comment: No, it is not.  I'll change it now, thanks.

Comment: Do you already know that $\zeta_q\in L$ and you want to check that it is in $L^G$?

Comment: That is correct, thanks.

Comment: What kind of condition are you after. For example, these conditions are equivalent to $\mathfrak P\cap k$ not splitting at all in $k(\zeta_q)$ - i.e. there is exactly one prime in  $k(\zeta_q)$ above $\mathfrak P\cap k$.

Comment: I am looking for, does it imply anything about splitting above $k(\zeta_q)$?  For example, if $L=k(\zeta_q)$, then $\zeta_q\in L^{G(\frak P)}\Leftrightarrow G(\frak P) = 1\Leftrightarrow \frak P\cap\cal O_k$ splits completely.  You can post that as an answer.